# I want to transfer a work in progress from one machine to another in Git like TFVC Shelveset

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc

I use VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) and have some work in TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) and different work in a Git Repository (repo) as we transition from TFVC to Git.
I frequently (twice a week?) start work on my powerful desk-side machine, but then need to hit the road.
With TFVC, that takes me about 30 seconds... From my desk side I create a shelveset. I then unshelve that shelveset on my Surface Pro... Off I go.
How do I do that with Git?
Most responses I've seen to similar questions involve many, many steps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a branch. Commit your changes to your branch. Push the branch to the remote. Merge when you're done.

Comment: Using DS for desk-side an NB for notebook... The objective is that the code that was a work in progress on DS is now over on NB.  I think create a branch has code on DS. Commit changes has the information on DS. Push to remote has them on the Server. But they aren't on the NB yet. I'll try this... by adding the pull from the NB. But I think that's:
1) Branch
2) Commit
3) Push (from DS)
4) Pull (from NB)
One thing I'll look for is to make sure I don't trigger our continuous deployment build... Back later with results.

Comment: I'll try more in the morning... I see that the "Merge" was done from the NB. That got the files over on the NB. But then when I did a sync, changes made to the file never made it up to the server. The good news is that the branch didn't kick off our CD (Continuous Deployment) build. But at the moment I think it's safe to say, this is one area where TFVC has the upper hand. I don't have this working yet and I'm already and twice the number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Mann - Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. Using the Visual Studio 2017 UI with your guidance, here's what worked for me:

1. Create a branch - kztransfer in my case.
2. I went to Branches and right clicked on master to select "Merge from..." then then selected "Into current branch:" as kztransfer.
3. I then pushed the branch up to the remote.
4. On the second machine I went to branches again and under remotes/origin selected kztransfer. I then right clicked and chose "Checkout"
5. And now I have the code on my other machine.
   Thanks!
   Note: I had changes in master first... going forward I would likely have a local branch already and not need to do the merge from master to kztransfer...